# How do I add a page to block in privoxy?

Tags: privoxy

I was having trouble finding the answer on youtube, google, or privoxy.org

Most tutorials end at getting privoxy installed and set up.

So I have everything installed and set up. Now I want to block www.apple.com/itunes/ using privoxy. I want to be able to access www.apple.com but do not want access to www.apple.com/itunes.

I am assuming I need to do something in the `user.action` file?

I'm fairly surprised I did not come across anyone with a similar question here on superuser. Seems like everyone is fine with privoxy's default add block settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have windows. I recommend you download Notepad++ and then make a "Find" search "Find in Files" and specific the configuration files location of privoxy. Then you search for the following :

> Blacklist

or

> WhiteList

Then in the file that will conclude in the above search, you can add your URL ; try whitelist www.apple.com and blacklist block www.apple.com/itunes .

The reason we do the search as above, is to find the fine that has the URL block list. A text based search inside privoxy config files should reveal the file. The file contents should look like this :

> ######################################################
>
> ## Blacklist
>
> ######################################################
>
> { +block }
>   www.apple.com/itunes
>
> ######################################################
>
> ## Whitelist
>
> ######################################################
>
> { -block }
>   www.apple.com

Comment: nope. on ubuntu and had to create a blacklist.actions file but it works fine. ONE HUGE PROBLEM though. On the blocked page there is a link that gets you right past the block T_T "See why this block applies or go there anyway." that defeats the whole purpose T_T

Comment: found it "enforce-blocks 1" set to '1' in the config file will turn the feature off...but still

Comment: any chance you know how to configure privoxy to run on port 80 so that it runs without having to configure proxy settings?

Comment: the only thing I found out is that privoxy is unable to do that and that you have to use and configure the packet filter (like PF or iptables). You set the accept-intercepted-requests to 1. "If you don't trust your clients and want to force them to use Privoxy, enable this option and configure your packet filter to redirect outgoing HTTP connections into Privoxy."

Source : http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual

but I am guessing you read that already..

Comment: @JoshuaRobison: you can auto-configure proxy settings on Ubuntu. For Firefox, `pref("network.proxy.ftp", "127.0.0.1");
pref("network.proxy.ftp_port", 8080);
pref("network.proxy.http", "127.0.0.1");
pref("network.proxy.http_port", 8080);
pref("network.proxy.share_proxy_settings", true);
pref("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
pref("network.proxy.socks_port", 8080);
pref("network.proxy.ssl", "127.0.0.1");
pref("network.proxy.ssl_port", 8080);
pref("network.proxy.type", 1);`, chrome uses the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` settings in `/etc/environment`